# For Image, appending is not happening in Word Doc(.docx) in Java

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I have tried following code:

```
   File f=new File("stackover.docx");
   XWPFDocument doc=new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(new FileInputStream(f)));
  List<XWPFParagraph>  paragraphs = doc.getParagraphs();
  XWPFParagraph para =  paragraphs.get(paragraphs.size() - 1);
  org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun run=para.createRun();
    XWPFTable table=doc.createTable();
    XWPFTableRow row=table.getRow(0);
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(f);
    File fileName=new File("stackOverImage.jpeg");
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(fileName);
    File fileName1=new File("stackOverImage2.jpeg");
    FileInputStream fis1=new FileInputStream(fileName1);

    run.addBreak();

    run.setText("Append The value please");
    run.addBreak();
    run.addPicture(fis, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, fileName.toString(),        Units.toEMU(320), Units.toEMU(210));
    fis.close();
    run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
    run.setText("Append The value please 12");
    run.addBreak();
    run.addPicture(fis1, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, fileName1.toString(),  Units.toEMU(320), Units.toEMU(210));
    fis1.close();
    doc.write(fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
```

Note: The document is already saved & has header & footer.

If I try to append an image in a document which doesn't have header & footer, the above code works great. Although, size of file is increased after the execution, but while I try to open the file, it says **We're sorry. We can't open the file. We found a problem with its content**. Can you please explain the reason why this happening & solution? Thanks in advance.

I am using following jars:
1. Poi 3.12
2. Poi -ooxml-3.10.1
3. Poi-scratchpad-3.15
4. Ooxml-schemas-1.1
5. Xmlbeans-2.3.0
6. Dom4j-1.1

Error is like below:
[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem is that your jars are all from different versions of POI.

Before you do anything else, replace your jars with a single version of POI. I see you mixing at least versions 3.10, 3.12, and 3.15. The POI jars are not developed independently of one another, and mixing and matching does not work. Next, you do not need the scratchpad jar for XWPF documents.

Comment: Thank you @jmarkmurphy , I used all the poi jars of 3.15 version & it worked.

Comment: one more problem, when i try to append more than one picture(different picture) then it is  throwing the same error during opening of the file. Although, size of file is increased. When i keep on click on OK->YES & open the file, i can see everything (all the data including the images) are present at appropriate place & pages. When i try to do the same with the same picture then file is corrputed & that(2nd time/next page) picture is not displayed.  what could be the reason @jmarkmurphy

Comment: I have added pictures in the question. You may refer that for OK->YES. Can you please help @jmarkmurphy

Comment: I'm not real familiar with pictures specifically, but show me the code with two pictures inserted. Maybe I will be able to see something.

Comment: I'm using 3.14, and it works for me. I cannot insert images into the header and footer though, that does not work at 3.14

Comment: I have created a new file having header & footer. When I try to append the content between header & footer. It's working that is it's not giving any issue while opening the file & content is also proper. But it's not working for some special docx file. will look into this. Thanks a lot for your help :) @jmarkmurphy